# How to have a sheet NOT print when certain cells are a certain number in VBA (while loop)

Tags: excel, vba

I created a script that takes information from SAP and exports it into Excel. Whenever this macro is run, the number of returned rows are different each time.
i.e.
1st time: 4 rows
2nd time: 12 rows etc.

When these are populated onto a table, I then used power query editor to read the file and created a very simple ETL function.

In the workbook that the ETL is on, the extracted SAP is then pre-populated onto multiple sheets. However, sometimes some of those cells on the sheet are 0 because of the number of rows that are extracted.

i.e.

4 rows extracted from SAP only 3 of the sheets get filled.
12 rows extracted from SAP only 6 of the sheets get filled.

etc.

Currently I wrote the VBA to print ALL sheets like this:

```vb
Dim sh As Worksheet
For Each sh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If sh.Name = "V" Or sh.Name = "W" Or sh.Name = "X" Or sh.Name = "Y" Or sh.Name = "Z" Then  'it prints the worksheets that you want here there might be a chance that we have to add more sheets ? thats a worry of mine.
    sh.PrintOut Preview:=False, ActivePrinter:="Print&Go Americas", PrintToFile:=True, PrToFileName:=PSFileName 'make sure to change the printer name if you have to based on location'
    End If
Next sh
```

However, I am trying to avoid printing ALL of the sheets and just print the ones that have values on them so (as seen below) if cells D6, H6, H7 are not 0 then I'll tell it to print out. However,

```vb
if ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(“V”).Range(“D6, H6, H7”).Select <> 0 then worksheets.("V").PrintOut
elseif ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(“W”).Range(“D6, H6, H7”).Select <> 0 then worksheets.("W").PrintOut
elseif ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(“X”).Range(“D6, H6, H7”).Select <> 0 then worksheets.("X").PrintOut
elseif ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(“Y”).Range(“D6, H6, H7”).Select <> 0 then worksheets.("Y").PrintOut
elseif ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(“Z”).Range(“D6, H6, H7”).Select <> 0 then worksheets.("Z").PrintOut
elseif ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(“ZA”).Range(“D6, H6, H7”).Select <> 0 then worksheets.("ZA").PrintOut
elseif ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(“ZB”).Range(“D6, H6, H7”).Select <> 0 then worksheets.("ZB").PrintOut
elseif ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(“ZC”).Range(“D6, H6, H7”).Select <> 0 then worksheets.("ZC").PrintOut
else ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(“ZD”).Range(“D6, H6, H7”).Select <> 0 then worksheets.("ZD").PrintOut
```

doesn't do anything for me and tosses me an error.

So what I'm TRYING to do in the code above is to have when:

Cells d6 h6 h7 on sheet V are NOT 0, then I'll print it out.
Cells d6 h6 h7 on sheet W are NOT 0, then I'll print it out.
etc.

Comment: `If sh.Range("D6").value <> 0 and sh.Range("H6").value <> 0 and sh.Range("H7").value <> 0 then sh.PrintOut ...`.

Answer (score 0):

### Conditional Worksheet Printing

- Both solutions do the required with the main differences: the first is case-sensitive (e.g. `V<>v`) and it's harder to find the worksheet names to be changed.

```vb
Option Explicit
     
Sub printWorksheetsSelect()

    Const sAddress As String = "D6,H6,H7"
       
    Dim sws As Worksheet
    Dim srg As Range
    Dim sCell As Range
    Dim doNotPrint As Boolean
    
    For Each sws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        Select Case sws.Name ' or UCase(sws.Name) for case insensitivity
        Case "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z", "ZA", "ZB", "ZC", "ZD" ' add more
            Set srg = sws.Range(sAddress)
            Debug.Print sws.Name, srg.Address
            For Each sCell In srg.Cells
                If sCell.Value = 0 Then
                    doNotPrint = True
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next sCell
            If Not doNotPrint Then
                sws.PrintOut
                doNotPrint = False
            End If
        End Select
    Next sws

End Sub

Sub printWorksheetsMatch()

    Const sAddress As String = "D6,H6,H7"
    Const sNamesList As String = "V,W,X,Y,Z,ZA,ZB,ZC,ZD"
       
    Dim sNames() As String: sNames = Split(sNamesList, ",")
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet
    Dim srg As Range
    Dim sCell As Range
    Dim doNotPrint As Boolean
    
    For Each sws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If IsNumeric(Application.Match(sws.Name, sNames, 0)) Then
            Set srg = sws.Range(sAddress)
            For Each sCell In srg.Cells
                If sCell.Value = 0 Then
                    doNotPrint = True
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next sCell
            If Not doNotPrint Then
                sws.PrintOut
                doNotPrint = False
            End If
        End Select
    Next sws

End Sub
```

Comment: if i wanted to print it to a particular folder, how would i do that ?

Comment: No idea, but you can check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.sheets.printout) from Microsoft. But I think you already got that covered in your `For Each` statement. [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.exportasfixedformat) may also be worth reading.